# Wpf datagrid scrollbar freezes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

I am new to WPF. I have a datagrid that has around 10000 rows. To implement search and highlight functionality,the following code is implemented

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">

                        <local:CustomTextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content.Text}">
                            <!--InlineCollection="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource StringToXamlConverter} }"/>-->
                            <local:CustomTextBlock.InlineCollection>
                              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringToXamlConverter}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="." />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:SearchOperations.SearchTerm)"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </local:CustomTextBlock.InlineCollection>                                
                        </local:CustomTextBlock>                     
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value> 
            </Setter>
```

The search and highlight is working like a charm.But on click of the vertical scrollbar entire grid freezes. What could be the reason here?

Comment: My guess is that it's running the **Converter** for every row. Could you give it a minute to run it through to test that theory?

Comment: @MikeEason yes the converter has to run through each cell for in order to achieve search functionality.

Comment: Refer to this [Data Grid Freeze Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66729233/10369907)

Comment: Refer to [Enable Virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66729233/10369907) for solution

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `IsAsync` property on your `Binding`.

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="." IsAsync="True"/>
```

This will force your bindings to take place on a different thread, freeing up your UI from freezing. However, as you have lots of rows, this may take a while, so I would advise making use of `FallbackValue` too.

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="." IsAsync="True" FallbackValue="..."/>
```

This will provide a value while the asynchronous process is taking place, a typical value would be text, such as a "Loading..." message.

Comment: thank you for the solution but unfortunately it is not working.  What I have observed when I click anywhere in the grid the grid goes to not responding state. But when the grid is loaded,on mouse scroll wheel move the rows are scrolling.